# Consuming types declarations generated from JSDoc: TS7016

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I'm writing [a library called bexer](https://github.com/error-reporter/bexer/tree/72e1f7d8999c31a9ad6d217d72077ab7cf03af18) with many packages (`@bexer/*`) in one monorepo using https://lerna.js.org.
Each package contains typescript types defined inside JSDoc comments.
The task is to consume these types in a project that uses my library.

1. I presume that I have to generate type declarations (`*.d.ts`) which will get consumed by the target project.
2. I generate type declarations with `typescript@3.7.3-insiders.20191118` with the following `tsconfig.json`:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "noEmit": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "declarationDir": "./packages/bexer-types",

    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,

    "target": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node"
  },
  "types": [
    "chrome"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./packages/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./packages/rollup.config.js",
    "./packages/**/iife/*",
    "./packages/bexer-types/bexer-*"
  ]
}
```

3. In the target project I use the following `tsconfig.json`:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,

    "target": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node"
  },
  "types": [
    "chrome"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*",
    "./node_modules/@bexer/components/**/*",
    "./node_modules/@bexer/types/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules/@bexer/**/iife",
    "./node_modules/@bexer/types/node_modules"
  ]
}
```

4. After launching `tsc` in the target project I get such errors:

> node_modules/@bexer/types/bexer-index/esm/index.d.ts:18:24 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@bexer/utils'. '/home/ilyaigpetrov/Projects/bexer/packages/bexer-types/node_modules/@bexer/utils/esm/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>     Try `npm install @types/bexer__utils` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@bexer/utils';`
>
> 18 import * as Utils from "@bexer/utils";

So the `index.d.ts` from `types/bexer-index` has imports like:
`import * as Utils from "@bexer/utils";` which fail to locate type declarations at `@bexer/types/bexer-utils/esm/index.d.ts` and TypeScript suggests to add `declare module '@bexer/utils';` to the declaration file.

However prepending `declare module...` to `@bexer/types/bexer-utils/esm/index.d.ts` manually doesn't eliminate this error.

My questions:

1. Is my approach of generating type declarations the right way to consume types from JSDoc?
2. What is the right way of using generated @bexer/types in the target project?

**UPD**:
In the target project I have `globals.d.ts` with content:

```
interface Window {
  Bexer: typeof import('@bexer/types/bexer-index/esm/index')
}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I've found is:

1. Don't publish all type declarations as a separate package, only put shared type declarations as a separate package.
2. Put type declarations inside each published package: e.g. `@bexer/index/esm/index.js` should by accompanied with `@bexer/index/esm/index.d.ts`.